# use in/join into lambda expression in Entity FrameWork

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

Hi there i have one sql query as below.

```
select * 
from Customers as C 
where
c.CompanyID in (
  select CompanyID 
  from Projects 
  where Projects.ID in (
    select ProjectAssignment.ProjectID 
    from ProjectAssignment 
    where ProjectAssignment.EmployeeID = 7 
  ) or Projects.ID in (
    select T.ProjectID
    from Tasks as T 
    where t.AssignedUserID = 7
  )
)
```

How can i write it with lambda expression?

Answer (score 1):

Try that (not sure it working):

```
var projectIds1=ProjectAssignment.Where(pa=>pa.EmployeeID ==7).Select(ps=>pa.ProjectID);

var projectIds2=Tasks.Where(t=>t.AssignedUserID ==7).Select(t=>t.ProjectID);

var companyIds=Projects.Where(p=>projectIds1.Contains(p.ID) || projectIds2.Contains(p.ID)).
    Select(p=>p.CompanyID);

var result=Customers.Where(c=>companyIds.Contains(c.CompanyID));
```